# Trying to understand the motivation for the basic tableau construction rules in propositional intuitionistic logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

In chapter 2 of https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243704264_Intuitionistic_Logic_Model_Theory_and_Forcing there is an introduction and motivation for the rules for tableau construction in intuitionistic logic.  I don't understand why $S$ above the line sometimes gets replaced by  $$S_{T} = \{TA | TA \epsilon S\}$$ below the line, rather than simply preserving $S$. We see this transformation in the rules $$F\sim$$ or $$F\rightarrow$$  I understand what the $$ S\rightarrow S_{T}$$ shift does but I don't get how this corresponds to mathematical reasoning.  Why are we just throwing away the false statements?  The above reference does attempt to explain this but I can't make any sense of it.  Many thanks for your help.  Paul Epstein

Comment: Basically the issue is with the different semantics of $T$ and $F$ (see page 30): in classical logic $T$=True and $F$=False, while in the intuitionistic one $T$ means "we have a proof of ..." while $F$ means "we have not proved...". This reading is reflected in the basic result of Kripke semantics: if $w \Vdash \varphi$, then $w' \Vdash \varphi$, where $wRw'$. This means that once proved, $\varphi$ "stay proved" in the future (in every world that is "accessible" from the current one). BUT NOT vice-versa: something that is not (yet) proved can become proved later.

Comment: Conclusion: it is safe to add the $T$-formulas to the next branch (branches) of the derivation but not the $F$ ones.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Thanks.  I think I have enough to go on to continue reading the paper.  So is $$\sim X$$ different from $$FX$$ ?  I would think so.  By defnition, $$\sim X$$ means that no proof of X exists whereas $$FX$$ means only that we don't yet know a proof.  I'm still a bit unclear so I'd appreciate it if you could confirm.  I got confused previously, because I couldn't imagine "X is false" being different to "not X is true".

Comment: In [Intuitionistic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#RejTerNonDat) $\lnot X$ is $X \to \bot$ and it does not read as "X is False" but as "from a proof of X we have a proof of *absurdum*". See [BHK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer%E2%80%93Heyting%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_interpretation).

Comment: In Tableau $FX$ is not a semantical concept, but only a "syntactical" operator: we can use unsigned tableau and all works the same way.